# Nodejs loopback TCP latency 1-2ms?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, latency

When creating a TCP server/client connected through the loopback address in NodeJS, I'm getting 1-2 ms round trip times for simple, low-data messages.

I don't have too much context for how fast Node should be, but it seems that it **should** be <1ms as there aren't very many operations going on and loopback ping times are in the microseconds.

Is there some buffering built into the net package that I'm missing, or is this latency to be expected?

Server:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer((socket) => {
  socket.setNoDelay();

  setInterval(()=>{
    socket.write(process.hrtime.bigint().toString());
  }, 1000)



  socket.on('data', (data)=>{
    console.log("Completed in: " + parseFloat((process.hrtime.bigint() - BigInt(data))/BigInt(1e3))/1000 + "ms")
  })

});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Client:

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', () => {
    console.log('Connected');

});

client.on('data', (data) => {
    client.write(data.toString());
});

client.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Comment: use MultiAddr! tis the future :p

Comment: `socket.setNoDelay`: It attempts to optimize throughput at the expense of latency

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. I'm sure there's ways to optimize the interpreter, but if your use case needs real time response times (<1ms) maybe you should change your tech stack to some other language that can use cpu, multithreading, io, etc more efficiently.

Comment: A modified version of UDP should offer better performance too, if your project/job allows that.